# LUKS encrypted device gone missing

Tags: partitioning, encryption, disk, luks

The 2TB disk that I use as an encrypted backup, is now reported by Ubuntu as being just free space. The encryption was setup as a LUKS encrypted device.

The output of `sudo fdisk -l` reports:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6b6edeba

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

Note that there is no partition information reported (there was only one partition on the disk).

Trying to open the disk with `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc crypt1` returns the error:

> Device /dev/sdc is not a valid LUKS device.

Now luckily I have backups of the backup, so I can live with the data being going this time, however I need to know: What caused it and/or how I can fix it, because otherwise I can't trust my backup to be there in the future and I will have to find a different solution.

Edit1: Per request a screenshot of the Disks Utility:
[image]

This is on `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS`.

Comment: Can you also identify **Ubuntu** version? What does **Gnome Disk Utility** (aka 'disks') show for this device (eg. */dev/sdc*)?

Comment: I have updated my question, but mostly it just says: "Free Space" and "Disk is OK"

Comment: From: https://askubuntu.com/questions/643610/luks-partition-lost try **`testdisk /debug /log /dev/sdc`**

Comment: Can you upload the output from `sudo head -c 4M /dev/sdc | xz > 4M.img.xz` somewhere? This will dump and compress the first 4 MiB of the drive into a file named `4M.img.xz`, which might have some clues about what happened. In the future, I suggest making sure that the drive is partitioned with MBR or GPT. It is possible and common to create a LUKS volume out of the raw drive (without any partitioning), and many tools cannot recognize LUKS volumes, leading them to conclude falsely that the drive can be overwritten without harm. I suspect that is what happened here.

Comment: Thank you @david6 and vincent-yu for thinking with me.  I won't be posting the first sector of my disk here, as this should contain the LUKS header and from a general security viewpoint it seems insecure to post it on the internet, as it would no longer be possible to wipe the disk by deleting the header. Unfortunately I am pretty certain that in this case the LUKS header is already deleted. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Running `sudo file -s /dev/sdc` returns:

```
/dev/sdc: x86 boot sector
```

Making it very probable that the LUKS header, which was raw on disk, was overwritten by a bootloader. The default for Ubuntu without LVM seems to be to install a LUKS volume directly to the disk.

The system is actually dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu (should have mentioned this, sorry!). To find out the culprit (hint: It's always Microsoft): we parse the strings in the first sector of the disk:

`sudo dd bs=512 count=1 if=/dev/sdc 2>/dev/null | strings`

Which shows for the backup disk with the lost LUKS header:

```
Invalid partition table
Error loading operating system
Missing operating system
```

The default boot drive has Grub 2 and for the same command returns:

```
GRUB 
Geom
Hard Disk
Read
 Error
```

The Windows 10 disk with the Windows 10 boatloader:

```
Invalid partition table
Error loading operating system
Missing operating system
```

Bingo! Now I know that I manually installed the Windows bootloader only to the Windows 10 disk, as I had accidentally overwritten it myself with a Grub bootloader and I know the LUKS volume was still there afterwards. However, I have run several automatic Windows 10 repair utilities, as my Windows 10 install keeps freezing/crashing. So it could be possible that one of them decided to appropriate the backup disk for an extra bootloader.