# Undo "Create partition Table" with Gparted on luks encrypted disk

Tags: encryption, gparted

I mistakenly picked the wrong disk volume with GParted and chose either the "Create partition table" or "Partition->new" (not sure).

I realized the error before applying the change and exited GParted. I had an error message explaining me the disk was going to be invisible from the disk browser (or something like that) until I reboot my Linux. What I did.

My disk is not visible anymore from the disk browser after a reboot.
This disk is a data volume with no boot sector and no operating system: only data.

This disk was formatted with an ext4 partition and encrypted with cryptsetup in luks format.

Is there a way to undo this partition creation that seems to overwrite my old encrypted partition?

Answer (score 0):

If you have overwritten the LUKS header there is not much you can do, but you can run through some of the commands in one of my own questions, to see if that's the case: [LUKS encrypted device gone missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674709/luks-encrypted-device-gone-missing/675506#675506)

Also try `sudo cryptsetup luksDump <your device>` to see if the header is still there.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally used a backup disk to get my data back and didn't try your solutions.